# Testing FT230X USB i/f - best way?

Tags: usb, usb-device

I have designed in a FT230X chip to take RS232 Tx,Rx,CTS,RTS and convert to/from USB on a PC. The problem I am having is that I do not trust my terminal emulator RealTerm. I just cannot seem to get anything out of it that is related to the USB port. I can see it as VCP, but setting it up to the same parameters as when I go direct RS232 doesn't produce anything.
Any suggested alternatives or test strategies?

Comment: There's a thousand better terminal emulators than realterm - but if you want software recommendations you should probably be asking this on SuperUser SO.

Comment: The best test is writing your own software that uses either the VCP or D2XX (since it's FTDI) drivers to talk exactly what you will talk in your final design. For maximum control (and in Windows max bandwidth) you'll want D2XX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a hardware loopback.  If the following doesn't work, then either your device has problems or your driver has problems.

1) Connect TX and RX pins together.

2) Start terminal emulator software.

3) As you type characters, they will be transmitted then received back into your computer, then displayed on your screen.  If you have ECHO enabled in your terminal emulator then you will see 2 of every character you type.

4) To test a large amount of text, "upload" an ASCII text file, but first set the terminal software to capture everything.  Clean up the captured file, then compare against the original file that you uploaded.